# Can realmdb be used as embedded database in a springboot or any other standalone application?

Tags: spring-boot, realm, embedded-database

We are looking for an embedded database that ships with application jar file and runs along side the application. This database should also sync data with Mongodb Atlas. We have found Realmdb to be a perfect solution. However, the JavaSDK for realmdb is meant only for Android apps.
Is there any possibility of using realm as an embedded database in a springboot application?

Comment: Can you clarify what is meant by 'embedded database' in your use case? Realm is part of MongoDB - there are a number of SDK's for Ream - and you can also interact directly with Atlas via those SDK's too. Perhaps clarifying the question would help us formulate an accurate answer.

Comment: Hi @Jay I have modified my question. To clarify we want the database to run along the application so that there is no network IO while connecting to database. Yes, relam does provide lot of SDKs but all are meant to be used in mobile devices.

Comment: The SDK's are also fully supported at the desktop level as well. If you're not using a mobile device, or a desktop device, is this some type of embedded controller situation where there is no host device? MongoDB Atlas and Realm can be used in a variety of ways; through the SDK's, the lower level Application Services, the QueryAPI, Realm Remote Access, as well as hitting endpoints and calling server functions. None of that is usable for your use case?

Comment: hi @Jay, our specific usecase is to use in a Springboot application. Springboot is not an desktop application.

Comment: Spring boot isn't an application: It's a framework that allows a developer to build applications - it's also support RESTful services (which you can do with MongoDB Realm) and, most importantly, it supports [Spring Data MongoDB](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-mongodb) so there are a number of options for your to explore. When you have a specific coding question, post it and we'll take a look!